# In Eclipse using Maven, I would like to have my build directory in a ram drive. How do I specify project.build.directory?

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, ramdrive

I am using Eclipse to compile DITA files into PDF and it does a lot of manipulation of the intermediate files before producing the final pdf files. I would like to get these intermediate files onto a RAM drive to speed up the process.
The project.build.directory looks like the most likely candidate variable that Maven and Eclipse are using to communicate where "target" is put.

The other alternative is to have a workspace on the ram drive and work there but that will not be preserved through a crash or reboot so I would have to do an autosave every 5 minutes or synchronize my project very often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default pathes are declared in the [SUPER POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM).

Just change them in your project pom like this:

```
  <build>
    <directory>c:/build/target</directory>     -> this is ${project.build.directory}
    <outputDirectory>c:/build/target</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>c:/build/target</testOutputDirectory>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <outputDirectory>c:/build/target/site</outputDirectory>
  </reporting>
```